# Can I use a custom CCK Link field as URL for Ubercart Product Image

Tags: entities, ubercart

I created a custom link field for my Product content type using Drupal 6 and Ubercart 2.
Now instead of linking the Product image in the Product site to itself or show it as a slideshow I would like to create a link to the URL of the given field.

I found the function that displays the product image, which is called 'theme_uc_product_image' and replaced

```
 $output .= '<a href="'. imagecache_create_url('product_full', $first['filepath']) .'" title="'. $first['data']['title'] .'"';
```

with

```
$destination_url = $node->field_direct_shop_link[0]['url']; 
$output .= '<a href="'. $destination_url .'" title="'. $first['data']['title'] .'"';
```

but it didn't work out!

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance.
Best,
Manuel

Comment: can you cut and paste the HTML that it did generate?  that might help in figuring out what part didn't work.  but a first guess is that since this is D6, it isn't complaining about $node not being defined inside the theme function, but that is just a guess at this point.

Comment: sorry for my late reply. this is the html which it generated: `<div class="product-image"><div class="main-product-image"><a href="" title="Test Product">` it totally ignored my url! so it probably is because $node is not defined. do you know if there's an easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Digging into Ubercart, this is the theme function you are talking about:

```
/**
 * Formats a product's images.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
function theme_uc_product_image($images, $teaser = 0, $page = 0) {
  static $rel_count = 0;

  // Get the current product image widget.
  $image_widget = uc_product_get_image_widget();

  $first = array_shift($images);

  $output = '<div class="product-image"><div class="main-product-image">';
  $output .= '<a href="'. imagecache_create_url('product_full', $first['filepath']) .'" title="'. $first['data']['title'] .'"';
  if ($image_widget) {
    $image_widget_func = $image_widget['callback'];
    $output .= $image_widget_func($rel_count);
  }
  $output .= '>';
  $output .= theme('imagecache', 'product', $first['filepath'], $first['data']['alt'], $first['data']['title']);
  $output .= '</a></div><div class="more-product-images">';
  foreach ($images as $thumbnail) {
    // Node preview adds extra values to $images that aren't files.
    if (!is_array($thumbnail) || empty($thumbnail['filepath'])) {
      continue;
    }
    $output .= '<a href="'. imagecache_create_url('product_full', $thumbnail['filepath']) .'" title="'. $thumbnail['data']['title'] .'"';
    if ($image_widget) {
      $output .= $image_widget_func($rel_count);
    }
    $output .= '>';
    $output .= theme('imagecache', 'uc_thumbnail', $thumbnail['filepath'], $thumbnail['data']['alt'], $thumbnail['data']['title']);
    $output .= '</a>';
  }
  $output .= '</div></div>';
  $rel_count++;

  return $output;
}
```

First off, I hope you didn't go in there and start hacking away, but rather copied the above to your theme's template.php file and renamed it `YOURTHEME_uc_product_image()` and made your modifications there :)  But, either way, from the declarations of this theme function, the only data you have to work are in the `$images` argument plus anything uberfunky returned by ub's image_widget.  You might want to throw in some debug code to see if anything in there is what you are looking for like this:

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($images, TRUE) . '</pre>');
```

at the start of your copied function.  Just remember to clear your caches/theme registry so drupal sees your function.

Comment: Haha, no no I've copied the function to my template.php! So I threw in the debug code and got the array printed. But there's no information related to my URL. I've also added   `$node = node_load($nid);` this here, but still no changes..

Comment: if this is being displayed on a node page, you are sitting on www.yoursite.com/node/#nid#, so, you could grab the nid by doing something like `if (arg(0)=='node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) { $node=node_load(arg(1)); }`

Comment: so the node type is a Product (ubercart) and it's sitting on a url like this www.mysite.com/content/my-test-product! but this page has still got a nid right? does anyone know how to access it from within my theme_uc_product_image function? is it possible to do something like this `function theme_uc_product_image($nid, $images, $teaser = 0, $page = 0)` ?

Comment: Not to get into a deep discussion here, but if `content/my-test-product` is a node, that is an alias to it, and its system path is really `node/###` and drupal can access it via `$_GET['q']` or its `arg()` function and `arg(1)` will be the nid.

Comment: ok sorry, i'm still pretty new to drupal. so i've tried the following: `if (arg(0)=='node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) { $node=node_load(arg(1)); }

  $destination_url = $node->$field_direct_shop_link[0]['value'];
  $first = array_shift($images);

  $output = '<div class="product-image"><div class="main-product-image">';
  $output .= '<a href="'. $destination_url .'" title="'. $first['data']['title'] .'"';`  but then my page didn't load anymore, so there must be something wrong in the code..

Comment: It is looking like you aren't creating your `<a ... >...</a>` correctly at the very end.

Comment: the hyperlink is actually created correctly, because the a tag closes a few lines below, but the site is still crashing when I save my template.php with the following code: `if (arg(0)=='node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) { $node=node_load(arg(1)); }

  $destination_url = $node->$field_direct_shop_link[0]['value'];
  $first = array_shift($images);

  $output = '<div class="product-image"><div class="main-product-image">';
  $output .= '<a href="'. $destination_url .'" title="'. $first['data']['title'] .'"'; `